# Trying to use the Netbeans ProgressBar to show long running tasks, having problems with dependancies and libraries

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have an application built on top of NetBeans. We have some long running jobs that I'd like to keep running in the background, but allow the user to see progress on the bar on the lower right.

E.G:

[image: Opening Projects Progress Bar]

I can't seem to access it from my code.

Initially I didn't have this library

`org.netbeans.api.progress.ProgressHandle;`

`org.netbeans.api.progress.ProgressHandleFactory;`

I had to go out and hunt down the JAR file. That doesn't make whole lot of sense to me, I figure it should be available.

This creates an error when I try to call the ProgressHandle into effect, I get this error 
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openide.awt.StatusLineElementProvider …`

Followed by a stack trace. Obviously I don't have all the packages necessary to operate this.

What the big question is then, what am I missing as far as accessing these NetBeans libraries correctly?

Thanks,

Here's the code when I'm trying to call the progressbar into action

`

```
ProgressHandle progr;
 if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
          progr.start();
          progr.progress("Sending backup to remote server.");
… //Some code that sends a backup
 progr.finish();
```

`

I'll be rewriting this question a few times, until I think it's clear, I'm open to input

Comment: Did you know there is a swing component for this `JProgressBar`

Comment: I've used that. But I want it to be in that bottom right side of the netbeans screen. So it's a background item. Is that possible ?

Comment: [Example](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2010/01/18/cancellable-tasks-and-progress-indicators-netbeans-platform/)

Comment: "an application built on top of NetBeans"; are you building a [Netbeans Platform](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/) application or is Netbeans simply your development [IDE](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html)?

Comment: @predi Yes, it's a Netbeans Platform application. Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a module dependency on `Progress API`. Right click on your module > properties.Select Libraries from the left panel. Click Add to open up the module dependency dialog. Select Progress API and click OK. Now you have the dependency on Progress API and you can use it as

```
ProgressHandle ph = ProgressHandleFactory.createSystemHandle("My Task");
ph.start(100);
```

Edit:
Also u dont have to add any jar files.. The Progress API module dependency will take care of that

Comment: I can't find the progress API ? I'm at the project level, under Libraries, I clicked Add Dependency, and I do not see a Progress API.

Comment: A-ha, I finally found it. No idea why I couldn't for a minute there. But this answered my question beautifully. Thank you.